# How to get one column of one record in SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

I try to get full name of `@MechanicExpertTable` table by select query but get error that

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

My code:

```
DECLARE @MechanicExpertTable AS TABLE 
                                (
                                     Id INT, 
                                     FirstName NVARCHAR(128), 
                                     LastName NVARCHAR(128)
                                );

INSERT INTO @MechanicExpertTable
    SELECT 
        PROFILE.Id,
        PROFILE.FirstName,
        PROFILE.LastName
    FROM   
        EstimatedRialMechanicExpert
    INNER JOIN 
        PROFILE ON EstimatedRialMechanicExpert.ProfileId = PROFILE.Id
    WHERE  
        EstimatedRialId = @id

DECLARE @MechanicExpert1 NVARCHAR(128) = 
    SELECT TOP(1) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id ASC) AS rownumber,
        @MechanicExpertTable.FirstName + ' ' + @MechanicExpertTable.LastName
    FROM   
        @MechanicExpertTable
    WHERE  
        rownumber = 3
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the full name for а specific position, try with the following example. In your case, `ROW_NUMBER()` is used without `PARTITION BY`, so `TOP(1)` is not necessary.

Input:

```
DECLARE @MechanicExpertTable AS TABLE (
   Id INT, 
   FirstName NVARCHAR(128), 
   LastName NVARCHAR(128)
);
INSERT INTO @MechanicExpertTable
   (Id, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES
   (1, 'FirstName1', 'LastName1'),
   (2, 'FirstName2', 'LastName2'),
   (6, 'FirstName6', 'LastName6'),
   (7, 'FirstName7', 'LastName7'),
   (9, 'FirstName9', 'LastName9')
```

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @MechanicExpert1 NVARCHAR(128)
SELECT TOP(1) @MechanicExpert1 = FullName
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id ASC) AS rownumber,
        FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName
    FROM @MechanicExpertTable
) t    
WHERE rownumber = 3 

PRINT @MechanicExpert1
```

Output:

```
FirstName6 LastName6
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing parentheses. Add () for your sub query as and the code should be as below-

```
DECLARE @MechanicExpert1 NVARCHAR(128) = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id ASC) AS rownumber,
        @MechanicExpertTable.FirstName + ' ' + @MechanicExpertTable.LastName AS T
        FROM  @MechanicExpertTable
    )A WHERE   rownumber = 3 
)
```

**Note:** I have added TOP 1 in the selection as it was available in your script. Basically when you are filtering with RowNumber = 3 there are no chance of coming multiple rows. You can remove "TOP 1" from the script.

Comment: In this case I get two column

Comment: Not clear, when you remove TOP 1? Or from my adjusted query?

Comment: Your query has error : Must declare the scalar variable "@MechanicExpertTable".

Comment: Thats already in your query. I just updated the lower part of your query. Replace my script in your query, it should work